# python - Looking up a dictionary key in another file with two criteria

Tags: python, dictionary

After the end of my code, I have a dictionary like so:

```
{'"WS1"': 1475.9778073075058, '"BRO"': 1554.1437268304624, '"CHA"': 1552.228925324831}
```

What I want to do is to find each of the keys in a separate file, teams.txt, which is formatted like this:

```
1901,'BRO','LAD'
1901,'CHA','CHW'
1901,'WS1','MIN'
```

Using the year, which is 1901, and the team, which is the key of each item in the dictionary, I want to create a new dictionary where the key is the third column in teams.txt if the year and team both match, and the value is the value of the team in the first dictionary.

I figured this would be easiest if I created a function to "lookup" the year and the team, and return "franch", and then apply that function to each key in the dictionary. This is what I have so far, but it gives me a `KeyError`

```
def franch(year, team_str):
  team_str = str(team_str)
  with open('teams.txt') as imp_file:
    teams = imp_file.readlines()
  for team in teams:
    (yearID, teamID, franchID) = team.split(',')
    yearID = int(yearID)
    if yearID == year:
      if teamID == team_str:
        break
  franchID = franchID[1:4]
  return franchID
```

And in the other function with the dictionary that I want to apply this function to:

```
  franch_teams={}
  for team in teams:
    team = team.replace('"', "'")
    franch_teams[franch(year, team)] = teams[team]
```

The ideal output of what I am trying to accomplish would look like:

```
{'"MIN"': 1475.9778073075058, '"LAD"': 1554.1437268304624, '"CHW"': 1552.228925324831}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your `KeyError`?

Comment: Quote "Using the year, which is 1901, and the team, which is the key of each item in the dictionary, I want to create a new dictionary where the key is the third column in teams.txt if the year and team both match, and the value is the value of the team in the first dictionary." Could you please clarify that?

Comment: @CrazyPython  `KeyError: "'WS1'"`  What I want to do is return the franchID for the year (1901) and the team, which is the dictionary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this code suite your needs?

I am doing an extra check for equality, because there were different string signs in different parts of your code.

```
def almost_equals(one, two):
    one = one.replace('"', '').replace("'", "")
    two = two.replace('"', '').replace("'", "")
    return one == two

def create_data(year, data, text_content):
    """ This function returns new dictionary. """
    content = [line.split(',') for line in text_content.split('\n')]
    res = {}

    for key in data.keys():
        for one_list in content:
            if year == one_list[0] and almost_equals(key, one_list[1]):
                res[one_list[2]] = data[key]

    return res


teams_txt = """1901,'BRO','LAD'
1901,'CHA','CHW'
1901,'WS1','MIN'"""

year = '1901' 
data = { '"WS1"': 1475.9778073075058, '"BRO"': 1554.1437268304624, '"CHA"': 1552.228925324831 }
result = create_data(year, data, teams_txt)
```

And the output:

```
{"'CHW'": 1552.228925324831, "'LAD'": 1554.1437268304624, "'MIN'": 1475.9778073075058}
```

## Update:

To read from text file use this function:

```
def read_text_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as file_object:
        result = file_object.read()

    return result

teams_txt = read_text_file('teams.txt')
```

Comment: This worked as expected. Now I will have to change it to read the teams.txt file, but that shouldn't be too bad. Thanks!

Comment: @Ike48 Don't forget to accept an answer that worked for your situation.

Comment: @Kyrubas How do I open a file so that it is formatted like you have as `teams_txt`? I tried `text_content=open('teams.txt').readlines()`, but it gave me an `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def clean(_str):
    return _str.strip('"').strip("'")

first = {'"WS1"': 1475.9778073075058, '"BRO"': 1554.1437268304624, '"CHA"': 1552.228925324831}

clean_first = dict()
second = dict()

for k,v in first.items():
    clean_first[clean(k)] = v

with open("teams.txt", "r") as _file:
    lines = _file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        _,old,new = line.split(",")
        second[new.strip()] = clean_first[clean(old)]

print second
```

Which gives the expected:

```
{"'CHW'": 1552.228925324831, "'LAD'": 1554.1437268304624, "'MIN'": 1475.9778073075058}
```

Comment: This returned a `KeyError: 'BS1'` in `second[new.strip()] = clean_first[clean(old)]`. Also, I don't think this takes into account the year, which would change the original keys as well as the output.